# How to redirect the old addressed using mod_rewrite 

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I was able to use this code:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ _pages/_portfolio/port.html [NC,L]
```

to rewrite my sites webpage from:

```
http://nkonecny.com/_pages/_portfolio/port.html
to
http://nkonecny.com/portfolio
```

My question is there a way to redirect people that use the old URL that shows the full file path automatically to the new cleaner file path without going into my html and editing each link?
In other words if they typing `http://nkonecny.com/_pages/_portfolio/port.html` it will automatically land them on `http://nkonecny.com/portfolio` ?

Comment: I have wanted to do that for a long time. Don't know how though. I am watching for answers now. Good thing you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.tamingthebeast.net/articles3/spiders-301-redirect.htm) tutorial

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^_pages/_porfolio/port.html$ /portfolio [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ _pages/_portfolio/port.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue an [HTTP redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) instead.

```
^/somepath(.*) /otherpath$1 [R]
```